# check type of data jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

How can i get different type of data passed in my function

```
var d1 = {
    property1 : propertyArray, 
    property2 : true, 
    property3 : 20
};
var d2 = propertyArray;
```

alert should be of different type

```
if ( d1 !== d2 ) alert('yes both are different')
```

http://codepen.io/iahmad/pen/edwPzr

Comment: whosoever **down voting**  question OR answer, please explain/justify

Answer (score 0):

object access is not correct.

```
if ( d1.property1 !== d2 ) alert('yes both are different')
```

Answer (score -1):

Because a prototypeArray will be returned as Object in JS so you should use the function as below to check Type

```
var typeOf = function(value) {
  if (typeof value == "object") {
    return Array.isArray(value) ? "array" : "object";
  }
  return typeof value;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple way to check type of data passed using jQuery:

```js
$("#checkType").click(function(){
var a = "hello";
 var b = 123;
 var c = false;
    if (jQuery.type(a) !== jQuery.type(b)) {
     alert("yes both are different!");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="checkType">check type</button>
```